# Why can I not create Ad Set Optimized for App Events (i.e. Purchases)?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

When trying to create an ad set in FB Ads Manager optimized for app events such as purchases, it does not work. It shows me the error: "App Event Optimization requires both application id and custom event type for promoted object. "

I am already able to track App Installs fine, and I have standard events set up and enabled in my iOS app. What could be going wrong here? My FB analytics don't show purchases even though there have already been a number of them.

I even tried the codeless setup option, and that does not seem to respond.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue, just keep tinkering with the Facebook Developer settings until you start seeing the purchase data appearing in FB Ad Manager. I just noticed today that the purchases started tracking, and I did not push a new version of the app recently.